# Looking for a story from the 70s or 80s about alien humanoid bee people

Tags: story-identification

A human ship crash lands on a planet that is inhabited by bee-like humanoids that have six fingers.  A man from the ship is found by a wandering junior queen and is mistaken for a drone.  When he doesn't die after sex she decides to keep him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a novel or a short story?  If a short story, did you read it in an anthology or a magazine?  Do you recall any details of the cover art?

Comment: "Three survived" by Silverberg has bee-like aliens with six fingers. No sex though.

Comment: It might possibly be Rogue Queen (1951) by L. Sprague de Camp